# How to get C# project path not bin/Debug

Tags: c#, file, path

I need to get my project path. Not an absolute path but just a path to my `Resources` folder.

I am creating a WPF application and I need dynamic paths to Images and Fonts.

How to get an absolute path?

Comment: The project path is only meaningful in the developer tools. The path to the running executable is available from the `Assembly` instance for you executable. Easiest to get as `typeof(TypeInExe).Assembly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get my project path, not absolute path just path for my Resources folder

WPF resources are compiled with **Build Action** set to "Resource" so generally there won't be a file system folder called "Resource" in  your deployment that you can use typical file I/O to load stuff from.

[image]

Here you can see how resources are embedded in my resulting assembly, note the .PNGs (the view here taken from Jetbrains *dotPeek* but Redgate *Reflector* will do nicely too):

[image]

> I need Images and Fonts dynamic paths

However, to load images in your "Resources" **stream** folder try this:

```
    public static BitmapImage GetImage(string iconName)
    {
        BitmapImage icon;
        try
        {
            icon =
                new BitmapImage(
                    new Uri(String.Format("pack://application:,,,/MYNAMESPACEHERE;component/Resources/{0}.png", iconName),
                        UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
            icon = new BitmapImage();
        }
        return icon;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much;it was help me and also new information about build action

Comment: What if I don't have a WPF project but a console application?

Comment: @shinzou a console application with a **Resouces** folder?   Tell me a new one